# wordpress dynamic permalink point to a page that takes URL get parameters

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, permalinks

I want a structure such as www.training.com/courses/course/location where course and location change to a course name and a geographical location to dynamically translate to www.training.com/course/?course=course&location=location

The reason is I have a plugin to display course information based on course name and location that takes get parameters.

P.s. I don't want to manually add links into a .htaccess file to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the courses and locations associated with each other? If so...

I'd recommend a custom post type for "courses," with a custom, [non-hierarchical taxonomy attached](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies), and then use a custom field in that post type to attach the location information to each course.

The [Types plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/) would handle all of these things relatively easily (but you'd need to create a template to display that information, of course).

Answer (score 1):

If the URL structure is going to be predictable, you could try:

```
// $url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$url = "www.training.com/course/?course=course&location=location"; 
$array = explode('/',$url);
$rev_array = array_reverse($array);
$location = $rev_array[0];
$course = $rev_array[1];
```

Then edit the plugin code slightly to read these variables rather than get variables.